# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specifiedd

Tags: python-3.x

I'm running Python code and I get this error:
"File

```
"C:\UsersMe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
```

But I do have this file in the said location:

[image]

Please help.

Tried to delete the file and put it again.